# Dissociate an account from a question

Tags: support, user-accounts

I am thinking about turning my account in a professional one.

However there are a few questions I asked in the past I would be a little bit annoyed if they would still be attached to my account. Is there a way to remove the link between my account and the question? I would like to not delete the question as people took time answering them and they might be useful for other people.

How can I do this?

Comment: *I would be a little bit annoyed if they would still be attached to my account* Why?

Comment: @KyleKanos because they could not look professional as I consider them as naive questions. Now it is likely very psychological but I prefer to completely remove that from my mind and not having to "worry" about this in the future.

Comment: Even naive questions can be evidence of not only your curiosity in general, but of your own personal growth. Isn't that something to be proud of?

Comment: @KyleKanos conceptually I agree with you and I wouldn't judge someone based on that. But if someone in the professional world look at this (few chances) and if this person doesn't think the same way, then it would be bad. I prefer not taking any risk.

Comment: Probably relevant: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5789/25301

Comment: Really, I doubt that anybody will go trawling through your old posts to see how 'professional' you were a decade ago on a physics site.

Comment: The easiest way is probably to abandon your account and start a new one, which you can register with your real name and everything. I wouldn't worry though, everybody had to learn the basics once.

Answer (score 9):

You need to use the [contact](https://physics.stackexchange.com/contact) link and explicitly request dissociation. See [this meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/96746/263383) for more information.

Note also that you cannot delete questions with positively scored answers anyway.

Comment: The exact criteria is: 1) more than 1 not deleted answers 2) has an accepted answer 3) any of the not deleted answers have at least 1 upvote